# Добавление цветного наложения к фоновому видео

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как добавить цветной оверлей к подобному видео, как показано здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

HTML

```
<div>
  <div id="outer">
    <div id="home-top-video">
      <video autoplay loop muted width="100%">
        <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. We suggest you upgrade your browser.
      </video>
      <div id="home-text">
        <div><img src="http://marquesslondon.herokuapp.com/images/logo.ee1689ee.png"></div>
        <h3>LIFESTYLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#home-top-video {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#home-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Fiddle здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/kggv3213/1/

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Add color overlay to video background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48962072/7394871) от участника  [@methuselah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436493/methuselah).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48962072/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете попробовать псевдоэлемент с градиентным фоном:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
#outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#home-top-video:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:1;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(65, 0, 255, 0.4),rgba(255, 0, 232, 0.3));
}

#home-top-video {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#home-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="home-top-video">
      <video autoplay loop muted width="100%">
        <source src="http://view.vzaar.com/2710053.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> Your browser does not support the video tag. We suggest you upgrade your browser.
      </video>
      <div id="home-text">
        <div><img src="http://marquesslondon.herokuapp.com/images/logo.ee1689ee.png"></div>
        <h3>LIFESTYLE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48962094/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>